# reactjs user authentication logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I'm trying to implement a user authentication feature to my react app and my approach is as follows.

I have created a **auth** file like

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

    export const AuthContext = createContext();
    export function useAuth() {
       return useContext(AuthContext);
    }
```

And used it in my **App.js** like follows

```
<Switch>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={false}>
        <LoginLayout path="/" component={Login} exact />
        <LoginLayout path="/register" component={Register} />
        <HomeLayout path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <HomeLayout path="/evc" component={EvcStations} />
      </AuthContext.Provider>
</Switch>
```

I have created a **PrivateRoute** file to handle routing if authentication is false.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import {useAuth} from '../../services/auth'
import React from 'react';
import { Route,Redirect  } from 'react-router-dom';

    function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
        const isAuthenticated = useAuth();
        return (
            <Route {...rest} render={(props) => 
                isAuthenticated ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ): (
                <Redirect to="/" />
              )}
            />
        );
    }
export default PrivateRoute;
```

I've used my PrivateRoute in the `HomeLayout` as follows.

**HomeLayout.js**

```
const HomeLayout = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    return (
        <PrivateRoute {...rest} render={matchProps => (
            <div id="">
                <div className="DefaultLayout mx-auto">
                    <div className="Header"><Header /></div>
                    <div><Component {...matchProps} /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )} />
    )
};
export default HomeLayout;
```

This is where i'm having an issue

If the authentication is false it will correctly redirect to the login page. But if the authentication is true i'm getting a error message

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You are passing render to `<PrivateRoute  render={}/> and using Component in PrivateRoute which is not passed

Comment: Yeah.That was the issue.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't forward your component to your `PrivateRoute`

```
const HomeLayout = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

    return (
        <PrivateRoute {...rest} component={Component} render={matchProps => (
            <div id="">
                <div className="DefaultLayout mx-auto">
                    <div className="Header"><Header /></div>
                    <div><Component {...matchProps} /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )} />
    )
};
export default HomeLayout;
```